# DragEffects usings DevExpress Drag&Drop

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using Devexpress (unfortunately) to perform dragdrop from one DXGrid to another.

In my ViewModel I got methods like `OnDragOver` where i would like to change the cursor. But DevExpress `GridDragOverEventArgs` seem to not support this feature?

```
 private void OnDragOver(GridDragOverEventArgs e)
{
 ...
 if(...)
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move;

}
```

Does anybody know how I can set the Cursor to the standard Windows Drag&Drop cursors?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can simply handle the GiveFeedback-event and change the cursor to your liking.

```
    private void OnGiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Effects == DragDropEffects.Move 
            || e.Effects == DragDropEffects.Copy
            || e.Effects == DragDropEffects.Scroll)
        {
            e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
            Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Hand);
        }
        else
            e.UseDefaultCursors = true;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

please be aware that having those events in your ViewModel is breaking the 
MVVM-pattern. Have a look at AttachedBehaviors, they will let you implement 
Drag&Drop-operations in a nice and seperated fashion

Comment: Where do you set e.Effects?

Comment: within the DragOver-event, just as you did in your code-sample. you may want to ommit the DragDropEffects.Scroll-check in my GiveFeeback-event

Comment: Maybe you read the question before you answer it? e.Effects is not supported for `GridDragOverEventArgs`.

Comment: now i understand why you are obviously unhappy with DevExpress...Drag&Drop of rows should be  handled by the view within the grid - ...where the DragOverEventArgs actually do support it ;)